# How to update data using _id in node_js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, nodejs-server

I tried crud operation using node js and mongodb.all crud operation is working fine expect update method.I tried to find and update method but its showing error.how to fix it.

updated method

```
db.collection('Ecommerce').updateOne({ _id:new ObjectId(req.params.id)},{ $set: req.body});
```

I tried to run showing this type error how to solve it.
MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Comment: Take the _id property out of the req.body object?

Comment: _id properly means i could not understand.can give some example code

Comment: this code also used to findone method its working fine and showing data.but update only its showing this type of error

Comment: That's makes sense, it's only the update that's trying to modify the object. And if you don't know how to remove a property from an object, I'd suggest some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your req.body also contains `_id` which is immutable field of mongo. you need to remove it in your request body

```
delete req.body._id;
db.collection('Ecommerce')
    .updateOne(
        { _id:new ObjectId(req.params.id) },
        { $set: req.body }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

*Jairo's* answer is good but you might love to use `.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)` instead of `.updateOne({},{})`